# Better wayto turn a grouping field into a table header in R?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I've got a dataframe with a date field, a factor, and a numeric. For each date, there are five rows of associated data:

```
date term count
2019-01-01 cheddar 5
2019-01-01 swiss 4
2019-01-01 edam 5
2019-01-01 gouda 2
2019-01-01 brie 5
2019-01-09 broussard 5
2019-01-09 provelone 4
2019-01-09 mozzarella 5
2019-01-09 gouda 2
2019-01-09 brie 5
```

My desired output looks something like this:

```
Week of 2019-01-01
cheddar 5
swiss 4
edam 5
gouda 2
brie 5

Week of 2019-01-09
broussard 5
provelone 4
mozzarella 5
gouda 2
brie 5
```

I could obviously write a loop with lubridate, but that seems like the wrong way to do this. Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't understand your desired output. See if this is it: `split(dat[-1], dat[1])`. (`data` is the name of your dataframe.)

Comment: The desired output is basically a text file that will be emailed to end users who have trouble reading tables.

Comment: And that worked brilliantly, thank you!